# What is the relation of the Four Heavenly Kings in Detective Dee: The Four Heavenly Kings?

Tags: detective-dee-four-heavenly-kings

In previous films, the subtitle of the film related back to the main case Dee is working on.

But in *Detective Dee: The Four Heavenly Kings* the initial investigation was staged by the mercenaries hired by Empress Wu to get Dee to live his place so that a couple of them could steal the Dragon Taming Mace and later the discovery of the Wind Warrior's plan to get revenge on the Tang Empire for their betrayal.

The only time the Four Heavenly Kings is mentioned is when Yuchi follows Dee's clues to where he had hidden the Dragon Taming Mace and to me it seems like a very minor thing for the subtitle compared to the previous films.

So is there any other relation of the Four Heavenly Kings in the film that would warrant it being in the subtitle?